# Neofetch and Screenfetch show completely different RAM results

Tags: ram

Recently I started using neofetch instead of screenfetch due to more information displayed in the first one. However, I noticed that one-by-one run screenfecth and neofetch show majorly different results. The first one:1900MB RAM used && the second one: 2500MB RAM used.   What could it be caused by? Which result is the most accurate? Which one should I use?

Comment: screenfetch shows the same memory used as the System Monitor application. Does your screenfetch show the same  memory used as the System Monitor does too? System Monitor -> Resources tab updates in real time, so whatever matches System Monitor is the more accurate of the two terminal programs.